SPFx for SharePoint 2019 CSS Page Layout Question
I am building a custom webpart for my SharePoint 2019 onprem using SPFx. The thing I dont quite get is how Page Layout is detected in my css.
For example I have here a fresh webpart here that I just generated using "yo @microsoft/sharepoint".
I made changes to it render but adding the following code
public render(): React.ReactElement<IPageCarouselProps> {
return (
  <div className={styles.pageCarousel}>
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div>Numbers:</div>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
        <div className={styles.column1}>1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

}
}
and with the following CSS
@import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';


.pageCarousel {
  .container {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

  .row {
    @include ms-Grid-row;
    @include ms-fontColor-white;
    background-color: $ms-color-themeDark;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .column1 {
    @include ms-Grid-col;
    @include ms-sm2;
    @include ms-md2;
    @include ms-lg1;
    @include ms-xl1;
  }

so it looks like this in my work bench

My question is, how can the css detect that the width of the webpart have change if I change the layout from "One Column" to "Two Columns"

I was hoping that since I make it "Two column" the number should go to the next line? But the only time it change is when I the screen size.

Note: Even at a "Three Columns" my "@include ms-sm2;" and "@include ms-md2;" is not getting applied. Aren't they supposed to kick in when the space or layout width for my webpart have change?

